# How can you calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \exp(\sin(x))dx$ exactly?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking a computational statistics class and I have to calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \exp(\sin(x))dx$ numerically (Monte Carlo integration) **and** compare the numerical result to the *exact* result. The problem is, how can one canculate the exact value of the integral? The antiderivative doesn't seem to exist in terms of elementary functions. Mathematica gives me this:

[image: Mathematica doesn't compute the antiderivative]

Not only that, Mathematica also cannot calculate the definite integral:

[image: definite integral isn't calculated]

And since Mathematica cannot do it, I don't think other softwares can, though I'm not sure. Of course, Mathematica can do the numerical integration

[image]

But that's not what I need! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Any answer would highly depend on your definition of "exactly".

Comment: I doubt the integral can be expressed in any way that you would want. Presumably you should compare the result of Monte Carlo integration to a better numerical approximation from a CAS.

Comment: @Bumblebee by exactly I mean the same value you'd obtain from the analytical solution, given that some analytical solution exists.

Comment: @runway44 what does CAS stand for?

Comment: @Bumblebee I believe they mean that the solution can be expressed using elementary functions

Comment: @Sigma: I doubt that the existence of a such closed form. For example, look at the even simpler integral: [error function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) But you should be able to write the answer as an infinite series easily.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like solution that can be expressed with elementary functions @Sigma

Comment: @SomeGuy I think this function doesn't have elementary antiderivative but I suppose there exists some analytical method to calculate it.

Comment: There are methods to get numerical approximations to any desired level of precision. Is this what you mean by "analytical method to calculate it"? Also CAS stands for computer algebra system (like Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To integrate

$$\int_0^1 e^{\sin(x)}\ dx$$

take first $x = \sin^{-1}(u)$, so $dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\ du$, then

$$\int_{0}^{1} e^{\sin(x)}\ dx = \int_{0}^{\sin(1)} \frac{e^u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\ du$$

and now note that, by using the general binomial theorem and the identity $(m)_k = (-1)^k (-m)^{(k)}$ converting the falling and rising factorial power,

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} &= (1 - u^2)^{-1/2} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{k} (-1)^k u^{2k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1/2)_k}{k!} (-1)^k u^{2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^{(k)} \frac{(u^2)^k}{k!}\end{align}$$

so that, by simply multiplying the series, we have

$$\frac{e^u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^{(k)} \frac{u^n}{n!} \frac{(u^2)^k}{k!}$$

And integrating, we get, noting that we should combine $u^n$ and $(u^2)^k = u^{2k}$ to $u^{(2k + n)}$,

$$\int_{0}^{\sin(1)} \frac{e^u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}\ du = \int_{0}^{1} e^{\sin(x)} dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2)^{(k)}}{(2k + n + 1)} \frac{[\sin(1)]^{2k + n + 1}}{n! k!}$$

More generally,

$$\int e^{\sin(x)}\ dx = C + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2)^{(k)}}{(2k + n + 1)} \frac{[\sin(x)]^{2k + n + 1}}{n! k!}$$

. Note that this is a hypergeometric series in two variables. To see that, you should first note the identity $\frac{2^{(n)}}{1^{(n)}} = n + 1$, thus

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2)^{(k)}}{(2k + n + 1)} \frac{u^{2k + n + 1}}{n! k!} = u \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2)^{(k)} 1^{(2k+n)}}{2^{(2k+n)}} \frac{(u^2)^k u^n}{k!n!}$$

so it looks like some sort of

$$F_\mathrm{hyp}(a; b; c; x, y) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{(n)} b^{(2n+k)}}{c^{(2n+k)}} \frac{x^n y^k}{n! k!}$$

double hypergeometric function in $u = \sin(x)$ and $[\sin(x)]^2$. But I don't think this particular form has any official name, though with some work maybe it can be reduced to known ones. The Horn functions [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_function) come closest, with the doubled index; but none have a $2n+k$ index in *both* numerator *and* denominator of the coefficient part. Two-variable hypergeo are obscure, though, at least from Wolfram's point of view, because it does not implement them.

Welcome to this new and exotic world.

Comment: There does exist a general two variable hypergeometric function in Wolfram functions, but the $2n+k$ cannot be split into $a\cdot(n+k)$, so there is probably no closed form with it.

Answer (score 4):

Since $1$ is not a natural bound of integration for this problem, it is pretty clear that you would have to have an indefinite integral for this to have any chance of success. By contrast, if the upper limit were $\pi,$ you get the nice answer:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \exp(\sin(x))dx = \pi  (\pmb{L}_0(1)+I_0(1)),$$ while for $2\pi$ you get an even nicer answer:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp(\sin(x))dx = 2 \pi  I_0(1).$$

(with $I$ being the Bessel function and $L$ the Struve $L$ function.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bumblebee commented, for the definite integral, compose Taylor series for the integrand
$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^5}{15}-\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^7}{90}+\frac{31
   x^8}{5760}+\frac{x^9}{5670}-\frac{2951 x^{10}}{3628800}-\frac{x^{11}}{3150}+\frac{181
   x^{12}}{14515200}+\frac{2417 x^{13}}{48648600}+\frac{58913
   x^{14}}{4151347200}-\frac{5699 x^{15}}{2554051500}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$$

Integrate termwise and use the bounds to get
$$\int_0^1 e^{\sin(x)}\,dx\sim \frac{60970121917}{37362124800}=1.63186977\cdots$$ while numerical integration gives
$1.63186961$

**Edit**

The next term in the expansion is $-\frac{52635599 }{20922789888000}x^{16}$ that is to say that its contribution to the integral is $-\frac{52635599}{355687428096000} \sim -1.48\times 10^{-7}$ which is not much.

**Update** *(almost eight years later)*

Using
$$e^{\sin(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^n(x)}{n!}$$
$$I_n=\int \sin^n(x)\,dx=-\cos (x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeomtric function.
$$J_n=\int_0^t \sin^n(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}-\cos (t) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(t)\right)$$

For $t=1$, the partial sums converge very fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \sum_{n=0}^p \frac {J_n}{n!} \\
 0 & 1.0000000 \\
 1 & 1.4596977 \\
 2 & 1.5960355 \\
 3 & 1.6258589 \\
 4 & 1.6310267 \\
 5 & 1.6317681 \\
 6 & 1.6318589 \\
 7 & 1.6318686 \\
 8 & 1.6318695 \\
 9 & 1.6318696 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The way I understood it, Big O notation here means that $O(x^{16}) \approx 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sigma. Yes, I shall prove it in a few minutes.